# PDF and PHP. How can I read the field data?

Tags: php, database, pdf

I'm looking for some help..

I need to create a web page (PHP) that will read an uploaded PDF, and save inside a database all the pdf's textarea/checkbox etc..

Someone can suggest a good PHP class? I tried the FDF library.. but is not working on PHP 5.3

Comment: cant see why it was downvoted, so +1 ;)

Comment: oh, I'm sorry.. wasn't my "goal" to make some subjective "difference" between library..

Comment: I don't mind recommending libraries, but I'd say this was downvotable since there's no prior demonstration of effort. A web search for "php pdf parser" will net several viable results, imo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [PDF Reader](http://heartofthefyre.us/PDFreader/)? It works with PHP 5

Answer (score 1):

If you're used to using frameworks, then the [Zend PDF](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.html) library might be just right for you.

Comment: @Rajan - you don't need to be using a web framework to use Zend - it's a component framework, from which you can take the pieces you want.